# Low-rank approximation to the Graph Laplacian matrix of a regular grid.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, approximation, graph-laplacian

As mentioned in the title, does anybody know any methods of efficient low-rank approximation $LL^T$ to the Graph Laplacian matrix $A$ corresponding to a square lattice? (except PCA)

Comment: Bumping this because I want to know the answer too.

Comment: That particular matrix is already really sparse. Can I ask why you want a low-rank approximation to it?

Comment: @JohnMoeller    cause I'd like to compute $B^{-1}A$, where B is also a sparse invertible matrix.

Comment: @Hugo In that case you're probably much better off computing $B^{-1}A$ by doing back-substitution (essentially solving $Bx=a_j$, for each column $a_j$ of $A$ -- this is more efficient for sparse matrices than computing the inverse and multiplying). Most math packages will give you a "left-divide" operation that does this automatically (in MATLAB it's $B\backslash A$ for example). Something to think about, it might not be applicable to your problem.

Comment: @JohnMoeller The complexity can be further reduced by solving $Bx=LL^T$ since $L$ is a low-rank approximation of $A$. Besides, $A$ is a very special matrix. That's why I'm trying to find whether there is someone working on the low-rank approximation of $A$.

Comment: @Hugo I actually doubt that you'll reduce complexity with a low-rank approximation. Suppose you choose your rank of $L$ as $k$. If $k=3$, your $L$ is _just as complex_ as $A$ itself (which has $3n$ entries), and then you have $L^T$ to contend with. And you're aiming for an approximate answer instead of an exact one.

Comment: @JohnMoeller  I can solve the linear system for each column of $L$, which has much fewer columns than $A$ does, thus I can obtain $y = B^{-1}L$ and then compute $x = yL^T$.